# How to select maximum date from each month in Python3 Pandas

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I've written below code to fetch date data from CSV file using Pandas.

```
import pandas as pd

data = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
print(data)
```

The output is mentioned below.

```
           dt
0  2020-09-24
1  2020-09-17
2  2020-10-29
3  2020-10-01
4  2020-10-08
5  2020-10-15
6  2020-10-22
7  2020-11-26
8  2020-11-05
9  2020-11-12
```

Now I wish to get maximum date for each month and the output should be as mentioned below.

```
           dt
0  2020-09-24
1  2020-10-29
2  2020-11-26
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert `dt` to datetime :

```
df["dt"] = pd.to_datetime(df["dt"])
```

Resample data on month and get the max :

```
df.resample(on="dt", rule="M").max().reset_index(drop=True)

      dt
0   2020-09-24
1   2020-10-29
2   2020-11-26
```

Answer (score 2):

`groupby` on monthly period and `agg` the `dt` column using `max`:

```
df['dt'] = pd.to_datetime(df['dt'])
s = df.groupby(df['dt'].dt.to_period('M'), as_index=False).max()
```

---

```
    dt
0   2020-09-24
1   2020-10-29
2   2020-11-26
```